# How to apply css class for image only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
.calendarList {  
       background-image: url('/resource3/hpsc/common/images/calendar.png');
       background-position: 135px 50%;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       cursor:pointer;
}

<input type="text" id="toDatepicker" class="calendarList" name="searchEndDate" size="20" >
```

Here the css class is applying totally to input text fields, when mouse over on text field, the cursor is showing hand symbol total input field,
I what to show the hand symbol for that image only not for whole text field.

Comment: Which image? I don't see an image. But then again, I don't see any javascript of jquery either.

Comment: I think he/she means the background-image

Comment: This one: `background-image: url('/resource3/hpsc/common/images/calendar.png')`

Comment: @samn I think so too, although it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think this is some kind of browse icon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible what you're trying to do.

Maybe you can add the image as a regular image (not as bg) and use some position: absolute and z-index to place it behind or in front of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make it happen with JavaScript, but it would be quite a convoluted solution. It's easier if you make the image a label instead of a background picture and position it on top of the input field.

```
<input type="text" id="toDatepicker" class="calendarList" name="searchEndDate" size="20" >
<label for="toDatepicker" id="datepickerLabel>
    <img src="/resource3/hpsc/common/images/calendar.png" />
</label>
```

CSS:

```
#datepickerLabel {
    position:relative;
    left:-20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tNwTz/ for a demo.

Comment: anwser is good but markup is bad because take that image in img tag which is only for display purpose